# insert into database value showing blank

Tags: c#, html

I am currently making a Register Page, I coded the layout with html, and I get value from the html input(`<input`) 
and insert into database. It did sucessfully inputed into the database but when I "select * from dbo.user" the value are showing blank

Comment: Makes sure to edit your post to add code you use to read/write value from DB. Preferably showing inline string constant values instead of reading from undefined controls.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");

if (!$conn) {
    echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (!mysql_select_db("mydbname")) {
    echo "Unable to select mydbname: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

$sql = "SELECT id as userid, fullname, userstatus
        FROM   sometable
        WHERE  userstatus = 1";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
}

// While a row of data exists, put that row in $row as an associative array
// Note: If you're expecting just one row, no need to use a loop
// Note: If you put extract($row); inside the following loop, you'll
//       then create $userid, $fullname, and $userstatus
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["userid"];
    echo $row["fullname"];
    echo $row["userstatus"];
}

mysql_free_result($result);

?>
```

SOURCE: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php